# Trouble Setting Up Maven on Mac OS

Tags: macos, maven

I'm never used a mac before and this is the first time I've tried to setup a coding environment. I've gone through multiple of the pages on here that give suggestions as to what is wrong, but still getting mvn command not found

I've set my `~/.bash_profile` as below:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME

M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-3.6.1
export M2_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

A `java -version` returns the following

> java version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)

So I believe that to be fine

A `echo $M2_HOME` returns the following

> /Applications/apache-3.6.1

Which from what I've seen would suggest that is also correct.

However, `mvn -v` returns the following:

> -bash: mvn: command not found

I've tried restarting the terminal and source `~/.bash_profile`

Any help greatly appreciated

James

Comment: Have you installed maven? Or did you just modified your bash profile? You have to install maven to make that work

Answer (score 0):

A `~/.bash_profile` like this works for me:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 12`
export M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.1
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Make sure you have a valid Maven installation under `/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.1` which has a `bin` folder inside with the actual executable.

Hope it helps.

### Edit-1

Check the difference between:

1. `/Applications/apache-3.6.1` vs.
2. `/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.1`

Comment: Yep that was the problem, feeling very stupid. Checked for typos multiples of times and did not pick up on that

Comment: Glad, it helped. Feel free to accept the answer, if everything is working as expected.